# while loop in t-sql with start and end year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to loop through the years and get the counts for each month on each year using below while loop . How can I achieve this by limited the number of years.

```
declare @start_year int=1999
declare @loop_year int
declare @end_year int=2015

WHILE (@end_year <2015)
BEGIN

Select    count(*) as rows,month(create_datetime) as month, year(create_datetime) as year
FROM      [table_name]
WHERE     year(create_datetime) =@loop_year
GROUP BY  month(create_datetime),year(create_datetime)
set @loop_year=@start_year+1
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a loop?  Loops/cursors are very inefficient.  It would be better to have the WHERE clause having the range of years in it and you will get a single record set with the count, month & year back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `WHILE` loop is messed up.  You are declaring `@end_year = 2015` and then saying `WHILE (@end_year < 2015)`.  I think you meant `WHILE (@loop_year < @end_year)`.

With that said, there is no reason to use a loop for this particular case.  This should accomplish the same results:

```
Select count(*) as rows,
    month(create_datetime) as month, 
    year(create_datetime) as year
FROM      [table_name]
WHERE     year(create_datetime) BETWEEN 1999 AND 2014
GROUP BY  month(create_datetime), year(create_datetime)
```